# Single User Application with Private Videos, Circumvent Password

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

We have a Vimeo Plus account with a large set of private, password protected videos and are building an internal application which will access a selection of these videos. So in this scenario we own the videos and the application which will access the videos. We would like to be able to embed and play the videos without entering the videos' password. Currently we are not able to find a way to achieve this using the API, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

the Vimeo API can only toggle your video's privacy settings, the API cannot grant playback to users outside of the privacy settings already provided. For example, you can use the API to set a video as password-protected and set the video's password, however you cannot use the API to authenticate and bypass password protection and allow playback.

Hope this helps!